# How to create a route with custom port in Rails 5?

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, custom-routes

I'm trying to create a dedicated health check route that uses a different port (3001) in Rails 5. my route should just render the text response "Up and running" but use a port different to the default app port while the app runs on the default port as usual.

```
def healthcheck
  render plain: 'Up and running'
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run **rails s -p 3001** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port by editing your `config/puma.rb file`. You’re looking for this line:

```
port ENV.fetch(“PORT”) { 3000 }
```

Change the `3000` to the port you want to use.